# Reference frame of high speed rocket

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reference-frames

Imagine a high speed rocket, traveling past a star. In the rocket's reference frame, the star's length is contracted. This is a lot a mass in a thin line, so it the rocket's reference frame, could it become a black hole? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a black hole form due to Lorentz contraction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28422/)

Comment: As pointed out below, the question as posed isn't really sensible in the framework of special relativity. I suggest you ask a question (by editing this one) that will make mathematical sense, but still replicate your question: what about an observer traveling at $.9999.. c$? You can still have the arbitrarily large Lorentz contraction that interests you without literally using a lightspeed frame.

Answer (score 1):

The point of view of a photon is not really a valid reference frame. This can be seen by asking yourself this question: if the speed of light is constant in all reference frames (a basic postulate of special relativity), then does a photon see itself traveling at the speed of light? As can be seen, this is utterly nonsensical.

Comment: I edited the question.