# Information density, Bekenstein Bound, and length contraction

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-information, information

Is it possible to observe a region of space that has information density greater than what the Bekenstein Bound  will allow when length contraction is involved? I.e. An object travels through the region of space close enough to the speed of light relative to the observer to appear more information dense than what the limit would permit. Or does it only make sense to calculate the Bekenstein Bound based off of an object's rest frame?

Answer (score 0):

Bekenstein bound says the entropy is bounded above by a quantity that is proportional to the total mass-energy. If an object is moving relative to you, it's mass-energy will increase thus increasing the upper bound allowed for the entropy.

Also see this - [Can a black hole form due to Lorentz contraction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/can-a-black-hole-form-due-to-lorentz-contraction)