# Is gravitational acceleration less affected by relativistic mass increase?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, acceleration

Acceleration due to mechanical force will lessen due to relativistic mass increase as kinetic energy becomes significant near c.

But if acceleration is gravitational, the gain in relativistic mass will produce a corresponding gain in gravitational attraction, so acceleration should be constant (for large M and small m), even as m nears c.

But that would imply that c could be approached and exceeded.

What slows the acceleration to prevent m exceeding c?

Comment: [This article](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/mass-energy-matter-etc/more-on-mass/the-two-definitions-of-mass-and-why-i-use-only-one/) doesn't answer _the_ question, but is important to take into account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a moving object curve space-time as its velocity increases?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95023/)

Comment: To correctly calculate the acceleration, you have to consider gravitational forces between moving bodies. The first post-newtonian approximation is given by the [Einstein–Infeld–Hoffmann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Infeld%E2%80%93Hoffmann_equation), while higher corrections can be found in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc//0108086)(equations $(1)\to (6)$). The result is non-trivial and depends on the masses and velocities of the two bodies.