# Is gravitational attraction increased by relativistic mass as well as rest mass?

Tags: relativity

Is gravitational attraction increased by relativistic mass as well as rest mass?

If so what would happen if an observer travelled at relativistic speeds? Would it appear to him that the whole universe had acquired a greater mass as it was moving at relativistic speed towards or away from him and hence start accelerating towards him under greater gravitational attraction?

Similarly would it mean that the universe was suddenly hugely more energetic that it was before with much higher balancing gravitational potential?

Comment: Thats why modern books donot teach relativistic mass.

Comment: See also [Does a moving object curve space-time as its velocity increases?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95023/does-a-moving-object-curve-space-time-as-its-velocity-increases)