# A thought experiment to prove that Newtonian gravity is incomplete

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames

A particle is at rest in one frame having mass $m$. It'll attract another mass proportional to its mass ( newtons law) .

We jump into another frame moving close to speed of light. In this frame it's mass will be very very large. It'll attract another mass proportional to its mass,which is larger than in the first frame.

So in the two frames  the forces will be different, Which can't be.

Hence we can say that the Newtonian gravity is incomplete. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are moving objects producing stronger gravity fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189015/)

Comment: Several problems here: most importantly "speed" (relative to what?) does _not_ increase mass, and Special Relativity does not describe gravitation.  Also you seem to be trying to cram Newtonian gravitation in where it does not belong (anywhere in Relativity!).