# Does an object traveling near the speed of light create a gravitaional field?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, particle-physics, mass

Does a particle traveling near the speed of light create an observable/measureable gravitational field around it?  I know most elementary particles travel near the speed of light and have no gravitational effect, but I'm talking about a more massive particle, say, iron for instance.

As a more specific example of what I'm trying to say; if you had a particle accelerator, could you create a decent, measurable gravitational effect in the epicenter of the circle outlined by the accelerator by accelerating a very heavy element close to the speed of light?

Comment: This question seems to be on a similar topic: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95023/does-a-moving-object-curve-space-time-as-its-velocity-increases

Comment: A photon has a non-zero "active gravitational mass". It does have a gravitational affect. Any concentration of energy causes gravity. If you had a box full of gaseous iron atoms and you heated it up, they'd move faster. And because you've added energy, the gravitational effect is greater. See Ernie's references below.

Answer (score 1):

The general theory of relativity predicts that kinetic energy will contribute to gravitational mass.  Here is a paper that explores the gravitational effect of kinetically energetic particles within a system: http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/gr-qc/pdf/9909/9909014v1.pdf.

Here is an interesting article by Frank Helle on the production of gravity by relativistic mass (mass created by relativistic velocity): http://www.quora.com/Relativity-physics/Does-relativistic-mass-have-gravity.  The conclusion is that a highly relativistic particle "does contribute to the curvature of space-time and thus to the gravity of the moving mass, but it is not exactly equivalent to a stationary particle of mass E/c^2 . . ."