# What if an object had enough speed that from another perspective it was enough to form a blackhole?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

Suppose a baseball is traveling through a vaccum towards another object extremely fast. If it's travelling fast enough then shouldn't its kinetic energy give it enough mass that the observer thinks it should collapse into a black hole and evaporate as Hawking radiation? How can this be reconciled with the perspective of a second object at rest with the baseball, which would have no reason to see a black hole?

Comment: Duplicate of [If a 1kg mass was accelerated close to the speed of light would it turn into a black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/50583)

Answer (score 0):

You start from a common and stubborn misconception: that objects acquire mass at high, relativistic speeds.

In reality it is the object's momentum $p$ that is relativistic:

$$p=\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},$$

where $m$ is mass, $v$ is velocity and $c$ is the speed of light.

See [relativistic mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity).

So your relativistic object could never acquire the mass needed to form a black hole.