# since Velocity is equivalent to Gravity does increasing the velocity of matter increase its mass?

Tags: mass, velocity, higgs, subatomic

If velocity is equivalent to gravity, does that mean particles with increasing velocity gain in actual mass associated with the curvature of space by matter?

if so, does that mass have an association with the Higgs particle?

Comment: Why do you say that velocity is equivalent to mass?  I can't think of a way of understanding that.  Also, I think your understanding of the Higgs mechanism needs work.  Particles don't collect Higgs particles and thus get heavier ... if that's what you are saying.

Comment: Your question does not make sense from the point of view that the Higgs only contributes a relatively small amount of mass to such entities as the baryons and mesons, the main contribution to their mass comes from virtual quarks and antiquarks and associated force carriers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass doesn't increase with increasing velocity. For example see [If a 1kg mass was accelerated close to the speed of light would it turn into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/if-a-1kg-mass-was-accelerated-close-to-the-speed-of-light-would-it-turn-into-a-b). It is possible to write relativistic equations of motion in a form where the mass $m$ is replaced by $\gamma m$, and $\gamma m$ does increase with speed, however this approach causes as many problems as it solves and is no longer used. These days when we refer to mass we mean [rest mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass), and this is an invariant.

The other point we need to make is that the Higgs boson is not responsible for mass. The [Higgs mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism) is resonsible for mass, and the Higgs boson that was observed at the LHC is a side effect of the Higgs mechanism. The Higgs mechanism is described using quantum field theory which is [Lorentz covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_covariance).

So there is no effect of the type you describe.