# Is the mass needed to create a black hole greater if the black hole is moving?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes

So my argument goes like this:

say we have an object that is nearly at the density required for a black hole.  Then we Lorentz boost into a new frame, the object is Lorentz contracted and therefore the density increases above the black hole limit.

As a mere change of frame can't have physical effects it surely can't create a black hole and therefore a moving black hole needs a larger density.

Is this correct and if it is how does this come out of General Relativity?

Comment: I'm afraid your starting point is a fallacy (albeit an appealing one when using the language of relativistic mass). See  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/if-a-mass-moves-close-to-the-speed-of-light-does-it-turn-into-a-black-hole

Comment: I dimly remember reading, I think it was in Kip Thorne's "Black Holes & Time Warps", that *all* of the object's mass must be within the critical radius for collapse to a singularity to occur. Recall that the object is not Lorentz contracted in the directions orthogonal to the velocity vector. I'll try to look that up.

Comment: Found it:  it's the [hoop conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoop_Conjecture).  From Figure 7.2 of Thorne's book:  *"According to the hoop conjecture, an imploding object forms a black hole when, and only when, a hoop with the critical circumference can be placed around the object and rotated"*.  I'll work on turning this into an answer after supper.

Comment: Your argument shows why this cannot be correct.  You cannot change the outcome by changing frames, as you correctly pointed out.