# Greatest relativistc mass possible for a single photon

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, photons, mass, quantum-gravity

I have been told that photons can not be blue shifted to the point where they become black holes, although a photon with a Planck scale wavelength would also have a relativistic mass equal to a black hole with a Schwarzschild radius on the scale of its wavelength.  (Imagine a photon stuck in a loop around its own relativistic mass).

So my question now is, what are the limits of relativistic mass or momentum that a single photon could have?

Also, by extension, how short a wavelength could it have?  If the wavelength gets to the Planck scale does it become a particle, or matter?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/

Comment: You may get a different answer if you ask about too very blue photons getting close.

Comment: A photon is by its definition a partile and has mass zero.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg   There is no relativistic mass for a single photon, no matter what its wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

In modern terminology, mass means invariant mass. See [Why is there a controversy on whether mass increases with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed) . The mass of a photon is zero. So to make this question more intelligible based on modern usage, a better title would be "Greatest energy possible for a single photon."

> I have been told that photons can not be blue shifted to the point where they become black holes

This is true because the criterion for being a black hole (light can't escape to infinity) is observer-independent. It doesn't mean that there's a limit on how much of a blueshift you can have. There is no such limit. Although it is true for a collapsing star, in its rest frame, that $r/m \lesssim G/c^2$ is a criterion for being a black hole, this is not true in other frames of reference. It would make sense in terms of Newtonian mechanics if the criterion was $r/m \lesssim G/c^2$, but general relativity is different because in GR the source of gravity isn't mass, it's the stress-energy tensor.

> Also, by extension, how short a wavelength could it have.

We don't have a theory of quantum gravity, so we don't know for sure how to interpret the Planck length. However, it probably shouldn't be interpreted as a minimum length scale. That would violate Lorentz invariance.

> If the wavelength gets to the Plank scale does it become a particle, or matter?

A photon is both a wave and a particle regardless of its wavelength. Modern physicists don't really use the term "matter" much, but to the extent that they do, they mean fermions. A photon is a boson regardless of its wavelength.

Comment: So can a photon have an energy density greater than a black hole?  Also, if it did, could it be bent around its own center of mass?

Comment: Pions aren't matter?

Comment: @JosephHirsch: *So can a photon have an energy density greater than a black hole?* As stated in my answer, density (or rather $m/r$) is not a general criterion for a black hole to exist. See the question linked to from my comment on your question.

Comment: "Modern physicists don't really use the term "matter" much, but to the extent that they do, they mean fermions." Not really. To a relativist, matter is simply anything that contributes to the energy-momentum tensor. To a cosmologist, matter is anything that obeys the non-relativist equation of state. To a condensed matter physicist, a Bose-Einstein condensate is most definately a state of matter.