# At very high speeds, why don't many things become black holes due to increase in mass and reduction in volume?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes, mass, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

When a body travels at a very high speed, as far as its concerned, everything is in motion except itself, so according to the body everything around it looses length in the direction of motion and gains mass. Keeping these two facts in mind, should it not be possible to travel so close to the speed of light, that due to increase in mass and decrease in
volume that for the moving body many things around it should turn into a black hole?

What's wrong here?
The only thing that I'm unsure about in this obviously false assertion is the relativity of mass and how its supposed to increase with velocity.

All answers will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a mass moves close to the speed of light, does it turn into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/)

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Shantanu! I've voted to close your question as a duplicate (link in G. Smith's comment). If the answers there still leave you with a question, you can edit your post to (1) link to the duplicate, and (2) specifically identify the question that the answers there don't address.