# Can something be a black hole in one frame of reference but not in another?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, black-holes, inertial-frames

So my understanding is because E=mc^2, and kinetic energy is included in E, something moving quickly relative to you gains mass in your reference frame, compared to that same object at rest. Black holes are dependent on density, which is dependent on mass and volume. If an object at rest is very close to being a black hole but not quite there, and then you move relative to it, would it appear to become a black hole? What are the ramifications of that?

Comment: Relativistic mass is an outdated concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/2451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a mass moves close to the speed of light, does it turn into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/)

Comment: Not all types of energy curve spacetime. The kinetic energy doesn’t.