# If an object is accelerated fast enough, will it become a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass, acceleration

I know that if an object is accelerated, its relativistic mass increases. Does this mean that if it is accelerated fast enough, it will become so massive that it becomes a black hole?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/23615 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a mass moves close to the speed of light, does it turn into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/)

Comment: There are some answers in the linked question that do not really answer (the point is that the object is accelerating). This is the "best answer" in my opinion: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3465/226902 see wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Apparent_horizon_of_an_accelerated_particle

Comment: The other answers talk about travelling at constant velocity. I think general relativity states  that acceleration can be thought of as gravitation . So if acceleration is very large then this would be equivalent to a strong gravitational field, perhaps sufficiently large to cause the object to collapse into a black hole?