# Paradox approaching the speed of light/Planck temperature?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes, speed-of-light, mass-energy

Paradox
If we accelerate an object (such as a proton) to closer and closer to the speed of light it will gain relativistic mass until eventually it gains so much (approaching the Planck Temperature) that it may turn into a Planck Scale black hole.
My problem with this is that the proton knows nothing about its relativistic mass increase in its frame of reference, so how can it turn into a black hole?

This is inspired by the paradox of two objects accelerating at exactly the same rate to relativistic velocities whilst connected by a string. The string breaks apparently, although I don't understand why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a mass moves close to the speed of light, does it turn into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/)

Answer (score 0):

In the context of special relativity, what does it mean to accelerate a proton near the speed of light? In the proton's frame light moves away at $c$ in all directions, so it's not moving.

If you want understand Bell's Space ship paradox: do the Lorentz transformations.