# If mass was to reach the speed of light it becomes infinitely heavy. Does this mean it has become a black hole singularly?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes, speed-of-light, speed

If mass reaches the speed of light, it becomes infinitely heavy. Does this mean that it has become a black hole singularly?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/2451

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible for an object with finite mass to travel at the speed of light. It is possible for an object with finite mass to travel arbitrarily close to the speed of light, but there always exists a reference frame in which the object is at rest. In contrast, there is no reference frame in which a massless object is at rest.

The question of whether an object's density is large enough for it to become enclosed in an event horizon, thus becoming a black hole, is a question which must be asked in the rest frame of the object. But the mass of an object, in its rest frame, is a relativistic invariant, and does not change with the object's speed.