# How fast spacecraft should be accelerated that it acts like a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, acceleration, equivalence-principle

I am little confused.Please correct me if I am wrong.
According to general relativity, there is no way to spot a difference between accelerating frame of reference and gravity.

Suppose a spacecraft is accelerated in space then we can not distinguish between the accelerating frame of reference and gravity.

My question is: How fast the acceleration should be that the spacecraft acts like a black hole? (Black holes have been observed therefore I am assuming such an acceleration should be possible.)

Comment: This question has multiple questions in one. It should be narrowed to focus on one question. Some of these questions are duplicates, so please check for duplicates too

Comment: This page describes acceleration near a black hole in details: https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s7-03/7-03.htm

Comment: Sort-of related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/123208

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an (apparent) event horizon in *any* accelerating frame: that is, if you are accelerating and keep accelerating then light from some distant events behind you will never reach you. The distance from the spaceship to this horizon is $c^2/a$, where $a$ is the proper acceleration of the spaceship; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon) for details (look under "apparent horizon of an accelerated particle"). Of course this horizon only persists as long as the spaceship keeps accelerating, which in practice isn't very long compared to the distances involved, so we never notice it in everyday life.

Note that this apparent horizon differs quite substantially from the event horizon of a black hole, in that it is only a horizon for the observer in the spaceship. This is to be expected. The equivalence principle has a lot of caveats that are *very* important in practice: a uniformly accelerating reference frame is equivalent to a *uniform* gravitational field *in a small enough region of spacetime*. Acceleration is thus not "the same" as gravity, but it acts "like" gravity if you only consider a small enough region of space and small period of time. Real gravitational fields (such as produced by a black hole) are very far indeed from being uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are thinking about is the [Unruh effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect). As far as the answer to your question is concerned, at any acceleration the observer would observe Unruh radiation which will be indistinguishable from Hawking radiation. However, if you want Unruh radiation to be highly significant the acceleration needs to be many order of magnitude high.

Comment: The OP is not thinking about the Uhruh radiation, but about acceleration. This post doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: @safesphere It does. The accepted answer simply spelt out mechanism for Unruh effect.

Comment: It didn’t even mention any radiation.

Comment: @safesphere So? If you have black hole you will have Hawking radiation and if you are in a frame that has radiation indistinguishable from Hawking radiation then it will be indistinguishable from a black hole.