Mass of my body from frame reference of fast moving particle
Suppose there is a particle that moves with near speed of light close to me. From the particle frame reference the particle itself is resting but my body moves with the near speed of light. So there should be relativistic effects for my body such as huge mass increase (and I should maybe to collapse into the black hole). But in reality there is no such mass increase.
How to solve this contradiction?

Your confusion is part of why modern physics education methods emphasise to only talk about rest mass. Relativistic mass increasing is just a bad idea. It is clear that energy is the thing that is increasing, because obviously kinetic energy adds to the energy of things.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/123208 And on why relativistic mass is deprecated: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/123208

mass doesn't change, but momentum can! and just like mass/energy, momentum can influence gravitational field. So you should replace mass with momentum and energy in your question

You always have $\mu$ mesons rushing by you at  more than 99% of c. How do you feel?

Mass does not change with velocity. The energy does.

"But in reality there is no such mass increase."  Why would you expect an increase?  In the particle's frame, your (relativistic) mass always has been, and always will be, enormous.  There's no reason for that to change.  (Others are quibbling about your use of the word "mass" to mean relativistic mass, but I think those quibbles do nothing to address the real heart of your confusion, since you could change the word "mass" to "energy" and still ask the same question.)

@naturallyinconsistent:  No, the OP's fundamental confusion has nothing to do with his choice of vocabulary.  Instead of asking why he doesn't notice his (relativistic) mass increasing, he could just as easily have asked why he doesn't notice his clocks slowing down.   I am personally annoyed when people use plural pronouns with singular verbs, but I usually try to answer their physics questions without going off on a tangent to lecture them about their grammar.

@WillO your reading of the OP's confusion is tolerable if it is on its own, but it is definitely not what other people are getting from this. It is, however, not tolerable for your view to attack ours; no student is confused that, when changing from one frame to another, that kinetic energy values assigned to various objects would differ. That's why our view is pedagogically superior. That's why it is sensible to attack the choice of wording. As for plural v.s. singular, I have no idea what you are on about, and I am not inclined to figure that out.
